# Parsing complex XML in PHP5

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Hello this is my first post.
i'm trying to parse an xml using php, but i'm stuck with it

example of my xml :

```
<xml xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
     xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
     xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
   <s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:CommandTimeout='30'>
      <s:AttributeType name='ows_LinkTitle' rs:name='Phone Number*' rs:number='1'>
         <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='512' />
      </s:AttributeType>
      <s:AttributeType name='ows_GSM_x0020_PUK' rs:name='GSM PUK' rs:number='2'>
         <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='512' />
      </s:AttributeType>
   </s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
   <z:row ows_LinkTitle='628558621183' ows_GSM_x0020_PUK='41016732'/>
   <z:row ows_LinkTitle='628558621181' ows_GSM_x0020_PUK='21783670'/>
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

i'm trying to get the value from each of 'z:row'
Any help is very appreciated. Thanks

i'm trying this code and it doesnt work

```
$xml_all = simplexml_load_string($xmlnya);

echo '<ol>';
foreach ($xml_all->xml->rs->z as $zrow)
{
 echo '<li> ows_LinkTitle: '.$zrow['ows_LinkTitle'];
 echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ol>';
```

Comment: Your XML is malformed (missing `s` namespace declaration, missing `s:ElementType` closing tag . Please fix that before trying to "parse" it.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php

Comment: You could try to use simplexml. The problem is that your xml string is far from being valid (no "s" namespace, a "<s:ElementType>" not closed).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=registerXPathNamespace

Comment: @naboen: if/when you fix the XML, are you looking to use any particular library in PHP? DOM, SimpleXML, XMLReader, other?

Comment: @all : i'm trying to use the code above but it doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippets below assume the (fixed) XML document is a string in `$xml`.

**SimpleXML**

```
$xml  = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$rows = $xml->children('rs', TRUE)->data->children('z', TRUE)->row;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $attributes = $row->attributes();
    $link_title = (string) $attributes->ows_LinkTitle;
    $gsm_puk    = (string) $attributes->ows_GSM_x0020_PUK;
    var_dump($link_title, $gsm_puk);
}
```

To read: [SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic), [`SimpleXMLElement::children()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.children), [`SimpleXMLElement::attributes()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.attributes).

**DOM**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$rows = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('#RowsetSchema', 'row');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $link_title = $row->getAttribute('ows_LinkTitle');
    $gsm_puk    = $row->getAttribute('ows_GSM_x0020_PUK');
    var_dump($link_title, $gsm_puk);
}
```

To read: [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagNameNS()`](http://php.net/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens), [`DOMElement::getAttribute()`](http://php.net/domelement.getattribute).

Answer (score 0):

When you get your xml fixed, you should have a look at the [simpleXML documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and specifically the [xpath method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

Comment: wont help the OP because it doesnt say that it also requires [registerXPathNamespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php) to make it work.