# Removing schema details from ouput xml and converting into array (Using PHP SoapClient and simplexml_load_string or SimpleXMLElement)

Tags: php, xml, soap, xml-parsing, soap-client

I am getting XML response from third party service,

```
$soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
$data = $soap->method($params);
```

Response looks like Stdclass object values

**$data** contains the xml inside the array object

**$data->resultResponse->any** contains below xml format,

```
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet"><xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Temp" ..... </xs:element></xs:schema><diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><DocumentElement xmlns=""><Temp diffgr:id="Temp1" msdata:rowOrder="0"><name>Siva</name><age>18</age>....<location>chennai</chennai></Temp><Temp diffgr:id="Temp2" msdata:rowOrder="0"><name>John</name><age>18</age>....<location>chennai</chennai></Temp>
```

I am getting below error When this xml using in to **SimpleXMLElement** or **simplexml_load_string** for array conversion ,

```
$res = $data->resultResponse->any;
$res1 = new SimpleXMLElement($res);
$res2 = simplexml_load_string($res);
```

For the both $res1 & $res2,

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in soap.php on line 40
```

I don't want the `"<xs:schema"` from that xml. I want `"<diffgr:diffgram"` values.

Previously, I used nusoap library for this. That is working fine for less memory data. Nusoap converts the whole xml into array. But, Php-Soap client gives only the first-level elements as objects/key.

I tried already some ways in loadXml in DOM and preg_replace. But those are not much helpfull

Please help me to resolve the problem.

**Original xml response getting from Boomerang,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<ClaimMISResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<ClaimMISResult>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Temp" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Temp">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
...
<xs:element name="location" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<DocumentElement xmlns="">
<Temp diffgr:id="Temp1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<name>John</name>
...
<location>Chennai</location>
</Temp>
</DocumentElement>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</ClaimMISResult>
</ClaimMISResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing complex XML in PHP5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580407/parsing-complex-xml-in-php5)

Comment: @RahulSingh In my question the problem is Not getting response from simplexml_load_string.

Comment: The "XML" you posted, is incomplete and broken. Additionally it looks like two XMLs combined, an XML document can only have a single root element node. Otherwise it is an XML fragment. DOM can load XML fragments with `DOMDocumentFragment::appendXml()`.

Comment: @ThW Thanks. That xml was not the original from response. I have updated now in question. Please check it.

Comment: what is code on your soap.php

Comment: Did you fix it? @Tamilvanan

Answer (score 1):

It's so easy, explode your result by </xs:schema>

```
$result = \explode('</xs:schema>', $data->resultResponse->any);
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($result[1])),true);
```